# Pass APDU command with WINSCARD

Tags: c#, vb.net, smartcard, smartcard-reader, winscard

below is the function from the winscard API

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]        
public  static extern int SCardTransmit (
                                          int hCard, 
                                          ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, 
                                          ref byte SendBuff, 
                                          int SendBuffLen, 
                                          ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, 
                                          ref byte RecvBuff, 
                                          ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

but the third parameter accepts the APDU command that is similar to something like 
`FF B2 A4 03 0E`
So am wondering how to pass that data in byte for to that parameter if i already have it in string form.
I know this could be a replication but i have failed to find a solution. Any links or other info will be so helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should probably be a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple. What you have there is a hexadecimal string, so you need a hexadecimal encoder/decoder package to convert these kind of strings to/from a byte array.

Note that the given hexadecimal string does not look like any APDU that I've heard of.